# Problema al enviar por socket archivos mayores de 23 MB

Tags: python, string, socket, ssh

Tengo una clase que hereda de `Process` que aprovecha una conexión `SSH` para hacer un port-forwarding a una máquina remota y enviar cierta cantidad de bytes.

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process,Pipe

class SshConnThread(Process):        

    def __init__(self,address,message,pipe):
        self.result = None
    self.address = address #puerto y direccion remota(127.0.0.1,5555)
    self.match = "[||]" #delimitador de lectura de socket
    self.message = message + self.match # esta es la cadena de bytes terminada por [||]
    self.pipe = pipe
    Process.__init__(self)

def run(self):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((self.address))
    s.sendall(self.message)
    data = ""
    while not data.endswith(self.match):

        data += s.recv(1040)

    s.close()

    self.result = data.split(self.match)
    self.pipe.send(self.result[0])
```

Pues bien, en el main de mi proyecto creo dos túneles SSH a dos máquinas remotas con `Paramiko`. Después, leo cierta cantidad de bytes de un archivo, divido esta cantidad en dos byte strings y envío cada cadena a través de uno de los dos túneles creados (utilizando la clase `SshConnThread` que puse anteriormente).

El proceso funciona perfectamente hasta que leo mas de 23 MB de un archivo. A partir de entonces, a pesar de realizar bien la división, el primer subproceso envía la cantidad adecuada a la máquina remota correspondiente, mientras que el segundo subproceso envía una cantidad considerablemente menor de bytes. Si realizo el mismo proceso ahora con 3 máquinas remotas, y dividiendo la cantidad de bytes entre 3, de nuevo a la primera máquina llega la cantidad correcta, a la segunda de nuevo llega una cantidad inferior, pero a la tercera también llega la cantidad correcta...

No es un problema de las máquinas virtuales, porque las he intercambiado entre ellas y siempre falla el segundo envío, y solo cuando leo más de 23 MB. No sé si tal vez tiene algo que ver con la cantidad de memoria que un subproceso puede reservar o algo por el estilo, pero no entiendo por qué solo falla el segundo envío...